# Not working: display value to modal from jquery-ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

somehow i can't display a value to modal through jquery/ajax. I am pretty new to jquery/ajax.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".Buto").on("click",function () {
        var dataID = $(this).data('id'); 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getid.php?id=' + dataID,
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            success: function(values) {   
                $('.form-group-title #title-edit').html(values.title);
                console.log(values);
            } 
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

The html code:

```
<div id="modal-table-edit" class="modal fade test" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="blue bigger">Edit website</h4>
</div>
<form class="form_validation_reg" method = "POST" action = "">              
<div class="modal-body">                        
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
    <div class="form-group-title">
        <label for="form-field-username">Title</label>
        <div>
            <input class="input-large" type="text" name = "title-edit" id="title-edit" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The query in getid.php?id= gives a good result ( $values['titel'] is filled).

Somehow the text field doesn't get filled with the value. Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the replies! I fixed it by the following code:
$( "input[ name = title-edit ]" ).val(values.title);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.form-group-title #title-edit').val(values.title);
```

Comment: Thanks Robert but unfortunately it doesn't fill the value yet. I have expanded the html code, i have some feeling that the other div tags which are before are maybe responsible. I think that jquery cannot find .form-group-title #title-edit?

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(values);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val(values.title)` instead of `.html(values.title)`
The val( value ) method is typically used to set the values of form fields.
See [val() jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Thanks nullpointer as well, for you the same: unfortunately it doesn't fill the value yet. I have expanded the html code, i have some feeling that the other div tags which are before are maybe responsible. I think that jquery cannot find .form-group-title #title-edit?

Comment: Weird that the $('.form-group-title #title-edit') selector does not work and $( "input[ name = title-edit ]" ) does... The id selector should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7B59w/